# Where the Ubuntu’s source can be gotten?

Tags: linux, open-source, ubuntu, linux-kernel, patch

Where can I get Ubuntu's source code? Actually I want It's kernel's code. I know I can get the kernel from kernel.org but as I found out that Ubuntu does some patching on the kernel I want to know what are those patches. And yes I know Ubuntu's kernel code can be found in an installed Ubuntu in the file system but thats just the code! I want specifically those patches separately and if any some comments or documents about them. Where can I get these things?

Comment: how about http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/linux ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/linux-image-2.6.32-24-generic

On the right, you can download a tarball with I assume contains the diffs from the vanilla kernel image.

Comment: That's not the correct package. You need [linux-image-*-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/linux-image-2.6.32-24-generic)

Comment: fixed the url to the package, thx

Answer (score 1):

Every mirror repository has it.

Try `man sources.list` and add a `deb-src` entry. Then it is just a `apt-get source` command away.